# mailbox.inbox not rendering from mailboxer gem, running rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, messaging, mailboxer

The other aspects of mailboxer work fine, I can send and receive conversations, I can show conversations both in my console and on my views.  However my mailbox.inbox and mailbox.sentbox don't seem to render right.

```
  <%= render current_user.mailbox.inbox %>
```

outputs the following in my browser window (similar output for when i render mailbox.sentbox)

```
 = content_tag_for(:li, conversation) do |conversation| %p = link_to conversation.subject,        conversation | - if conversation.is_completely_trashed?(current_user) = link_to 'Untrash', [:untrash, conversation], method: :post - else = link_to 'Move to trash', [:trash, conversation], method: :post
```

I've tried all sorts of things, removing 'render' gets me the following output:

```
   #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Conversation:0x4b73b48>
```

Any idea how to fix this? Please help, I'm a newbie at rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...accidentally left a _conversation.html.haml file from https://github.com/RKushnir/mailboxer-app...fixed it up with a new _conversation.html.erb file inbox renders fine now!